# Unmount external drive with LVM2 Physical Volume on it

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, unmounting, duplicity

I've got my Ubuntu 13.04 install backed up to my external hard drive using deja-dup.  I formatted the drive with lvm so I could use the rest of the drive for external storage while having the resize capeabilites of an lv.  When I plug the drive in to backup, it mounts and runs properly.  Backup's done, I hit the eject button to unmount the backup lv, everything still green.  I unplug the drive, noting the activity light is on but doesn't go off.

After doing this I want to access the storage, so I plug the drive in but get an error which reads:

```
Unable to access “storage” Error mounting /dev/dm-2 at /media/alex/storage: 
Command-line `mount -t "ext4" >-o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/dm-2" "/media/alex/storage"' exited >with non-zero exit status 32: 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock >on /dev/mapper/VG1-storage,
      missing codepage or helper program, or other error
      In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
      dmesg | tail  or so
```

I've messed around Linux and the command line long enough to know it's not mounting properly because it wasn't unmounted properly, but after a couple of week's worth of searching and hacking I'm still resorting rebooting in order to fix it.  What's the procedure to "unmount" a physical volume?

Comment: Are you deactivating the volume before removing it (`vgchange -a n /dev/vgname`)?

Comment: Yes, to no avail.  Says 0 logical volumes are active, but lvs still lists them and so does the "Devices" panel. Unplug, re-plug and I get the error